# Nodejs dependency weird behavior

Tags: node.js

Say that I have a server module called `server.js` and an api module called `api.js`, `server.js` is the main module that i'm running.

Now, In the server, I have some functions that exports some data about the server,
In the `api.js`, I want to get some data from the server exported functions by adding: `var api = require('./server.js');`

The problem is that I get the `server.js` code running twice, first time when i'm running it, second when the `api.js` running the `require('./server.js')`

Any suggestions to bypass this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it the other way around. Something like this:

In server.js:

```
api = require('./api.js');
api.exportData({data1: foo, data2: bar});
```

In api.js:

```
var data1 = 'defaultvalue1', data2 = 'defaultvalue2';

exports.exportData = function(dataObject) {
    data1 = dataObject.data1;
    data2 = dataObject.data2;
};

// rest of your code
```